# an error says "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable " on a print() line but I changed every int value to a str value

Tags: python, printing, typeerror

I am trying to print some information for a project I'm working on:

SnakePosX is an int value

SnakePosY is an int value

Direction is a string (either up, down, right or left)

ApplePos is a list containing 2 int values

SnakeLength is an int value.

I have turned every int value into a string like this: `{str(SnakePosX)}` even tho it was perfectly fine until I added ApplePos[1].
Here's the full string:

```
print(f"New pos: {str(SnakePosX)},{str(SnakePosY)} // Direction: {direction} // Apple pos: {str(ApplePos[0])},{str(ApplePos[1])} // Length: {str(SnakeLength)}")
```

Tell me if I need to add anything.

Comment: If the shown line causes the error then "ApplePos" is an int and not a list.

Comment: Please include the full error message in your question. You can try `print(type(ApplePos))` to confirm that it's an `int`. You don't need to convert to `string` inside a f-string interpolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ApplePos was an int instead of a list. I made it a list and everything works fine now.